# Issue in catching the thrown exception in Unit Test Case

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method that takes an argument Source Folder / Source File.I have handled the code in such a way that if Source Folder or Source File does not exist , it should throw DirectoryNotFound Exception or FileNotFound Exception accordingly.
Following is the Code Snippet

```
          Boolean isSourceExist = Directory.Exists(sourceFileorFolder);
          Boolean isFileExist = File.Exists(sourceFileorFolder);
            if (!(
                ((isSourceExist == true) && (isFileExist == false)) ||
                ((isSourceExist == false) && (isFileExist == true))
               ))
            {
                if (isSourceExist == false)
                    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
                else if (isFileExist == false)
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
```

While trying to unit test this method for negative scenario i.e providing a folder that does not exist, [ExpectedException(typeof(DirectoryNotFoundException))] fails in unit test case.
But the actual code responds properly by throwing the appropriate exceptions based on the inputs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need `if (!(((isSourceExist == true) && (isFileExist == false)) || ((isSourceExist == false) && (isFileExist == true))))` ?

Comment: Thanks Chetan. The condition you asked for is to ensure that the source must either exist as a file or a folder.

Comment: side topic: UT should not perform real IO.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could write two distinct tests, one for the file case, and one for the directory case.

Anyway, this code does very likely not behave as you expect. The code snippet you posted will always throw if either a file or a directory exists at `sourceFileorFolder` path.

If the path exists as a file, you throw `DirectoryNotFoundException`, else you throw a `FileNotFoundException`. Only if the file does not exist you proceed without throwing.

EDIT: I missed the `!` in the big `if` statement. Actually this method never throws, because the first `if` statement is entered only if the file does not exist (*not ((folder and not file) or (file and not a folder))* is the same as *not (file or folder)*). The smaller `if` statements behave as I have written above.

Comment: Thank you very much Lotti . I would like to add a point to your previous reply.This method responds correctly when i run the actual code i.e it throws Directory not found exception for invalid source folder and File Not Found Exception for invalid source file. But if I test this method,the following [ExpectedException(typeof(DirectoryNotFoundException))]  does not work

Comment: Then maybe the snippet you posted does not include the code that causes that behaviour? Or maybe it's slightly different from the code you are running? Posting the whole method would help.
--
Also it might help to explicitly state that you are using Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework.

Answer (score 0):

no need to go this complex, remove the upper if condition

```
Boolean isSourceExist = Directory.Exists(sourceFileorFolder);
Boolean isFileExist = File.Exists(sourceFileorFolder);

if (isSourceExist == false)
     throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
else if (isFileExist == false)
     throw new FileNotFoundException();
```